# How to control a short "animation" with a single bone?

Tags: rigging, bones, constraints

*I've never really rigged something before (not counting automatic weights ;).*

I've made a simple rig of a landing gear, and I'd like to have a single control bone control the whole unfolding sequence.

I've made a simple animation mostly showing what I want to bone to do by moving it along the Z axis:

[image]

I tried to setup various transform constraints to rotate the various bones according to the Z location of the control bone, but I must be doing something 
wrong, as they don't work as I expect.

[**Blendfile**](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/32194)

Is this even a good approach to rigging something like this?

Comment: What do you expect? The little flap (last moving part) should be moved before  the 'foot' reached the ground? I don't know about conventions,"Death to the Armatures by Christopher Kuhn" describes how to animate mechanical parts completely without bones.

Comment: @stacker I'm trying to make it so that moving `control_bone` on the Z rotates all the bones so that moving the control bone up retracts the landing gear, and moving it down extends it. Are armatures considered bad practice for    mechanical animations?

Comment: For this approach, I've always been using shape keys and the I rotate the elements using the 3d cursor and then use one bone to control the speed of the animation.

Comment: @gandalf3 You basically want the 'Action Constraint', which allows an object to act as a driver for an 'action'. I couldn't get it working enough to feel I could post an answer but the Tears of Steel quadbot has examples of it working.

Comment: What is the Suzanne.004 on layer 20 for?

Comment: @David That's just a manifold Suzanne that I keep in my startup .blend. Not related to anything in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/32204)**
I took your blend, made a copy of the landing gear and rig and deleted the animation.
I then added *[Transformation](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Constraints/Transform/Transformation)* Bone constraints to four of your bones; *arm1*, *arm1.001*, *pad*, and *pad_backflip*. Notice the different values of the Min and Max for the Source Z axis on the Transformation constraints. That is how I timed the different parts to happen at different times. Your *Control_bone* drives all of the Transformation constraints.

[image: gandalf style gif]